# OVER_QUERY_LIMIT - Distance Matrix API - Keyless access is deprecated

Tags: google-distancematrix-api

I intermittently get the error; even while using API Key with my request (distance-matrix api), does anyone have a solution?

"Keyless access to Google Maps Platform is deprecated. Please use an API key with all your API calls to avoid service interruption. for further details please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account."

Comment: Besides following the link and following their instructions, I'm at a loss.  That is to say, did you actually read what they're suggesting you do?

Comment: Yes. Our execution is straight forward get with api key supplied as a parameter in the url. The API Key is restricted to use only one API and No Application restrictions.

Comment: Looks like we have an answer, the developer had typed in param for key as "Key" in of the server configs and the reason for the resulting error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we have an answer, the developer had typed in param for key as "Key" in of the server configs and the reason for the resulting error –